# DB Server and Fully Qualified Domain Name

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, sql, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a hosted virtual server (Windows Server 2012 R2) that exists solely to host a few SQL databases.  I need to purchase a SSL certificate to encrypt data but purchasing a certificate requires that the server has a fully qualified domain name.  How do I create a FQD when the server doesn't host websites or have any domains associated with it?

Answer (score 0):

Host have IP, this IP have (or can have) some hostname. FQDN isn't property of website, it's just property of **any** host